# restful services not all Working properly after redeplyment

Tags: java, rest

I had created many web service using java , I had deployed it in Glassfish server and it is working fine , but I added some more web services and redeployed again, the new service is not working (on the server ) while it is working locally , so what am I missing ? I deleted the old version from Glassfish server, and deployed it again , but the new service is still not working (it is not finding it) ..

Here is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Login</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/phone/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and here on of the new services I had added :

```
@Path("/GetBranchs/")
public class GetBranchs {

    @POST   

    enter code here
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    public ArrayList<Property> CheckCredentials2(User user)
    {

        ArrayList<Property> lst = new ArrayList<Property>();



        try 
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.17.4.78:1521:DBDEV","salim","sal1m321");  

                    //step3 create the statement object  
                    PreparedStatement  stmt=con.prepareStatement("select distinct BRANCHARABICDESC,BRANCHCODE from vw_fulldetails  where STATUSACTIVEINACTIVE='01'");  

                    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();

                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                        //User usr = new User();
                        //usr.InitUser("","","","",rs.getString(1),rs.getInt(2),"",0,"",0,0,0,0,0);
                        //lst.add(usr);

                        Property prop = new Property(rs.getString(1),rs.getInt(2));
                        lst.add(prop);
                    }
        } catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);} 

        return lst;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since it is working locally i do not think code will help here. Can you check the log files of the server and your application? Any exception there? Also you are creating a war file? Could you rename it .zip and check its content?

Comment: its showing thid error , "The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request" , i renamed the file into .zip and its having all the web services , now what i have created before is working , but the recent web services is not ..

Comment: no stack trace at all? This exception appears most propably when you are making the rest request? Since it seems to my as if that the servlet is up and running and somethin internally crasses, could you "attach to process" and try to do remote debug or this is not an option?

Comment: Also, could you please :
1. edit your question and modify connection properties of the server...(ip, user name and password of oracle) -for your own security reasons..-.
2. Check that ip, user name and password correct and IP is accessible from that server (firewall, etc).
3. System.out.println(e); please replace it with log4j...and log more information like an extra string 'failed to connect with database'

Comment: no stack , usually this issue happening when i give wrong link , indicating that this service is not exist , is it maybe because of cash mem that is keeping the old version ? i dont have much experience actually , debugging is not an option as its working locally with no issue

Comment: ook ill consider these steps .. and see what i get ]

Comment: any way , i found the issue on the constructor , i used setters to set the values of the returned object and works fine , the question now .. Why ? just for my knowledge